# Cannot receive the last email from Gmail with OpenPop.NET

Tags: c#, email, openpop

I'm creating a console application. The app's objective is to get the last email with parameters from the mailbox, for example: If is from "example@gmail.com" and contains "test" on the subject, make something. That is, whenever a new email with these characteristics is received, it will do something. Only once per email.

First, the app will get already received email's ids to a list. Then, every 20 seconds, the app will see if there's any new email and, if it exists, will see if it contains the necessary characteristics. If it has the characteristics it will execute something, otherwise, it will continue to check the mailbox until some email appears.

```
class Program
{
    public class Email
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Assunto { get; set; }
        public string De { get; set; }
        public string Para { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public string ConteudoTexto { get; set; }
        public string ConteudoHtml { get; set; }
    }

    private static OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client _client = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
    private static List<string> _emailsProcessados = new List<string>();
    private static ManualResetEvent _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static void Autenticar()
    {
        if (_client.Connected)
        {

            _client.Disconnect();
        }
        _client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);//Faz a conexão ao Gmail               
        _client.Authenticate("email@gmail.com", "password");//Autenticação do utilizador
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) => {
            _quitEvent.Set();
        };

        MarcarTodosOsEmailsExistentesComoProcessados();
        var timer = new Timer(ProcessarEmails, null, 0, 20000);
        _quitEvent.WaitOne();                        
    }

    private static void MarcarTodosOsEmailsExistentesComoProcessados()
    {
        Autenticar();
        var messageCount = _client.GetMessageCount();

        for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
        {
            var uid = _client.GetMessageUid(i);
            if (!_emailsProcessados.Contains(uid))
            {
                _emailsProcessados.Add(uid);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessarEmails(object p)
    {            
        var messageCount = _client.GetMessageCount();
        for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
        {
            var headers = _client.GetMessageHeaders(i);
            if (headers.From.Address.Equals("emailsender@gmail.com") && headers.Subject.Contains("test"))
            {
                var uid = _client.GetMessageUid(i);
                if (!_emailsProcessados.Contains(uid))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("New email received");
                    _emailsProcessados.Add(uid);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using OpenPop.NET.
This library does not automatically update the mailbox, so it is necessary to re-authenticate in order for the mailbox to update.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0UsguTsdfErdnJnYVh3SnV0WXc?usp=sharing)'s my app if anyone wants to take a look.

Hope you guys can help me. Any questions, just ask.

Comment: You state "This library does not automatically update the mailbox, so it is necessary to re-authenticate in order for the mailbox to update." but then you don't reauthenticate in the `ProcessarEmails` function...

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Thanks! It already works!